# socket creation return -1 (Operation not permitted)

Tags: c, sockets, ubuntu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/ip_icmp.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    int n=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP);
    printf("%d",n);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know  why this program return -1.
Can you help me?

System configuration:

OS: Ubuntu 14.04

Language: C (-Wall -W -Wshadow -std=gnu99)

Comment: Why don't you check `errno`?

Comment: How can I check errno?

Comment: if (n == -1) perror("Unable to socket()");

Comment: My program return: Unable to socket(): Operation not permitted
-1

Comment: How Can I unlock creation of ths socket?

Comment: If I use sudo to run my program my problem don't exist Thank you